# Exporting Data List that contains lists of different dimensions to Excel.... or txt

Tags: r, dataframe, datalist

im having a problem when i try to export my data list 'c1', its a "list of lists" with two columns and variable numbers of rows as you can see.

```
> str(c1)

List of 8
 $ :'data.frame':       432 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ FECHA              : Date[1:432], format: "1980-01-01" "1980-02-01" "1980-03-01" "1980-04-01" ...
  ..$ El.Hato..21201210.I: num [1:432] 14 57 6 43 67 62 18 33 62 99.9 ...
 $ :'data.frame':       228 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ FECHA              : Date[1:228], format: "1996-01-01" "1996-02-01" "1996-03-01" "1996-04-01" ...
  ..$ Guanata..21205890.I: num [1:228] 32.8 90.7 131.4 67.1 84.4 ...
 $ :'data.frame':       348 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ FECHA                : Date[1:348], format: "1980-01-01" "1980-02-01" "1980-03-01" "1980-04-01" ...
  ..$ La.Pradera..2120044.C: num [1:348] 5 37 57 40 85 NA NA NA 33 184 ...
 $ :'data.frame':       432 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ FECHA                    : Date[1:432], format: "1980-01-01" "1980-02-01" "1980-03-01" "1980-04-01" ...
  ..$ Las.Margaritas..2120071.C: num [1:432] 11 14 3 15 66 45 6 7 12 29 ...
 $ :'data.frame':       432 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ FECHA                      : Date[1:432], format: "1980-01-01" "1980-02-01" "1980-03-01" "1980-04-01" ...
  ..$ Pantano.Redondo..21201060.I: num [1:432] 33.4 80.7 64.1 67.2 122.3 ...
 $ :'data.frame':       336 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ FECHA               : Date[1:336], format: "1987-01-01" "1987-02-01" "1987-03-01" "1987-04-01" ...
  ..$ Sabaneta..23065100.I: num [1:336] 140.8 46.7 114.7 73.4 129.2 ...
 $ :'data.frame':       384 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ FECHA                 : Date[1:384], format: "1982-01-01" "1982-02-01" "1982-03-01" "1982-04-01" ...
  ..$ Santillana..21206020.I: num [1:384] 38.5 89.8 52.5 187.7 119.4 ...
 $ :'data.frame':       336 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ FECHA    : Date[1:336], format: "1987-01-01" "1987-02-01" "1987-03-01" "1987-04-01" ...
  ..$ Tabio.GJA: num [1:336] NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

I tried to use the usual exporting data functions, and other sollutions found in here but the problem is the dimensions of my data list...

```
write.xlsx(mydata, "c:/mydata.xlsx")
write.table(c1, "c:/cluster1.txt", sep="\t")
```

I get this error always

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 432, 228, 348, 336, 384
```

Ill apreciate any help in this.

Kevin Davison

Comment: It is a list.  So you need to loop through the list and write it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the help files for `write.xlsx` and `write.table`. These functions accept data frames as arguments, not lists. You'll either need to convert this list to a data frame (use `ldply` from `plyr`), or simply write 8 different data frames using a for loop, as akrun suggests. If you just want to save the object for use in R at some later time, use `save` or `saveRDS.` Again, examine the help files of these commands and determine which one best suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer im gonna take a look at, now im trying to solve another R issue.  :(

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I just include the same date row to every list with 432 rows each, and fill it with NA's in order to export the data.